# ¿Como almacenar una cadena de conexión en una variable string en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de inventario, principalmente el sistema trabaja con Entity Framework pero dado a una situación puntual tengo la necesidad de usar `System.Data.SQLConnection` mi problema radica en que almaceno en una variable de tipo `string` pero me marca la línea como error, dice **Nueva línea en constante**.

El código es el siguiente:

```
 public class CustomConnection {
      private string cnn = "data source=127.0.0.1\sqlserver; intial catalog=dbInv; user id = ****; password = ****;";

      public SQLConnection conect() {
           try {
                var cn = new SQLConnection(this.cnn);
                cn.Open();
                return cn;
           }
           catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.Message);
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Nota aparte, pero realmente no deberías tener ese try-catch allí. No te beneficia en nada, y mas bien, pierdes el stack trace si llegara a suceder un error.

Comment: Otra nota, si la cadena no va a cambiar, sería bueno marcarla como constante. `private const string cnn = @"..."`.

Comment: Si piensas cambiar tu cadena deberías encapsularla en una propiedad @socorro-silva

Comment: Otro comentario es que podrías acortar tu código dentro del método poniendo ´return new SQLConnection(this.cnn)´ @socorro-silva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que la `\` dentro de una cadena `string` es un carácter especial. La solución es que en vez de `\` pongas `\\` o que antepongas un `@` antes de la primer comilla doble de la cadena.

Solución 1:

```
 public class CustomConnection {
      private string cnn = "data source=127.0.0.1\\sqlserver; intial catalog=dbInv; user id = ****; password = ****;";

      public SQLConnection conect() {
           try {
                var cn = new SQLConnection(this.cnn);
                cn.Open();
                return cn;
           }
           catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.Message);
           }
      }
 }
```

Solución 2:

```
 public class CustomConnection {
      private string cnn = @"data source=127.0.0.1\sqlserver; intial catalog=dbInv; user id = ****; password = ****;";

      public SQLConnection conect() {
           try {
                var cn = new SQLConnection(this.cnn);
                cn.Open();
                return cn;
           }
           catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.Message);
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Usaré la segunda opción @michael-traña

Answer (score 1):

Ese error se debe a que debes escapar las diagonales invertidas así `\\` para que tu cadena de conexión quede así:

```
private string cnn = "data source=127.0.0.1\\sqlserver; intial catalog=dbInv; user id = ****; password = ****;";
```

Answer (score 1):

Por que no lo usas directo desde un archivo de configuracion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>    

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="default" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PrismaNvo;User ID=sa;Password=xxx"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

uso

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
            {
```

Comment: Como podría ocultar la conexión al instalar la App en los equipos?

Comment: @SocorroSilva Encriptala